# Excel - How to use the OFFSET function where the reference is in one column but not in a static cell location?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So say I have data like this:

[image]

I want to find the date data highlighted in yellow using the value "Production" highlighted in green in the A column. However, the cell where location resides may change (the column does not change) as the table is updated from outside sources. How could I use the OFFSET function to get that date data? Or is there a better function to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula below assumes that your data don't extend outside the A1:AZ1000 range:

```
=INDEX(A1:AZ1000,MATCH("production",A1:A1000,0)+1,AGGREGATE(15,6,POWER(10,LOG10((B2:AZ2>0)*COLUMN(B2:AZ2))),1))
```

(the references to row 2 are because the data in your screenshot start on that row, so it identifies the first numeric column as the first column in `B2:AZ2` containing a value > 0)

The assumption made is that you want the value from the 1st numeric column that is on the row below where *production* is found (as, if you simply wanted the last row of the first column of numeric data then the position of *production* would be irrelevant).

(if your version of Excel is earlier than 2021/Office 365 then the formula must be entered as an [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula))

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This definitely works, but is there a reason this would be better than the offset formula below?

Comment: Offset() is a volatile function, which means that it recalculates every time something on your worksheet changes, which can have a negative impact on your sheet's performance. Also, if you're always going to be interested in column E, then a much simpler formula would be `=INDEX(E:E,MATCH("production",A:A,0)+1)`

Comment: @scorbin it does not just recalc anytime something on the sheet changes, it recalcs anytime anything on any open excel workbook changes.

Comment: Ok, that is all good to know. Right now we will always be looking at the data in column E, so the simpler formula should be good.

Answer (score -1):

```
=OFFSET(A1,MATCH("production",$A:$A,0),4,1,1)
```

Match finds the row of "production"
Offset uses the match as it's 2nd argument (rows) from A1, then over 4 columns and retrieve 1x1 cells.